# MVC 3 - decimal type validation against number with decimal point

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, decimal

In my Model I use a field with decimal type:

```
public decimal Profit { get; set; }
```

Then I use the Model in Razor edit view (generated by VS wizard). The number loaded from data base is displayed correctly in the input field, e.g 4 as 4,00 (as decimal point in my culture is comma).

Problem is when the field loses focus I see validation error message: *The field Profit must be a number.*

Next when I change comma to point losing focus doesn't display mentioned message but when I submit the edit form it generates validation error message: *The value '3.4' is not valid for Profit.*

It works only with number without point and comma.

How to resolve it by DataAnnotations (it would be the best) or at most in the other way?